# Could not find SVN source control repository options in xCode 9.0

Tags: svn, version-control, ios11, xcode9

I have upgraded my xCode to 9.0. I am using SVN repository for source control. With previous version of Source Control I could check all the SVN commits under source Control "History", but with latest xCode 9.0 I am not getting "History" option.

I have attached following screen shots for both old and new xCode versions.

**This is screenshot of xCode 8.3.2** >>

[image: This is screenshot of xCode 8.3.2]

**This is screenshot of xCode 9.0** >>

[image]

Can some one please help me out in this issue.

Comment: I have the same options in XCode 9 as you have. As an alternative, you can go to the version editor (top right corner) and select "log"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the top left corner of Xcode 9 click on the "Source Control navigator" icon (see image). This will display what you are looking for!

[image: Xcode 9 - Source Control navigator]

Comment: Thank you Chxyz for your reply (+1). I already found this couple of hours back. Now my concern is to add/attach my code to SVN repository. I would be thankful if you have any inputs on that. Please check my updated question.

Comment: @iLearner Your question was about accessing the commit history in Xcode 9. This answer answers that question.  Select a branch from the source control navigator to view the history. Now you're asking about setting up a SVN repository. Which question is your real question? If your real question is setting up a SVN repository in Xcode 9, ask a new question.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk Yes Chxyz answers my question, but I find out this earlier to Chxyz's answer. But no issues this will help someone else. I will open new question for SVN set up as its not yet resolved.